# MySQL Query executed with PHP gives different results with nothing changed between executions

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL that gets executed by a PHP script. To summarize, the script first clears the table "members". Then it opens a file called members.db and reads all the lines into an array, and then for each line in the array, it splits the line up into components and inserts each of those components as a new row into the "members" table.

The thing is, every time I execute the PHP script, some rows don't get inserted, and it's a different set of rows every time. For example, on one exection, 135 rows out of 144 might get inserted, and on the next execution, 137 will get inserted, and on the next, 129, etc. The rows that don't get inserted seem to vary randomly from one execution to the next, and I'm not changing anything in between.

What could cause this?

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM members;");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE members AUTO_INCREMENT=0;");

$lines = file('cgi-bin/sigphon/members.db', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++){

    $line = explode(';;', $lines[$i]);

    $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $password = md5($line[11] . $salt);

    $query = "  INSERT INTO members (
                    surname,
                    names,
                    home,
                    affil,
                    country,
                    email,
                    private,
                    interest,
                    specialty,
                    jointime,
                    password,
                    salt)
                VALUES (
                    '{$line[1]}',
                    '{$line[2]}',
                    '{$line[3]}',
                    '{$line[4]}',
                    '{$line[5]}',
                    '{$line[6]}',
                    '{$line[7]}',
                    '{$line[8]}',
                    '{$line[9]}',
                    '{$line[10]}',
                    '{$password}',
                    '{$salt}'
                    )";

    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Use mysqli and prepared statements.

Comment: `for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++){` would be better to use: `foreach($lines as $line){` otherwise, you may be skipping some if the index doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm sure `$salt` includes characters (or bytes) that break your query. As GhostGambler said, let the old and deprecated mysql_* functions behind and use prepared statements with placeholders (mysqli or PDO). This will take care of your problem. Because you're generating pseudo random strings, the rows that can't be inserted will differing.

Comment: Right, I guess it would've been smart to for something in the code that varies randomly if my problem seems to be happening randomly. I will look into that.

Comment: MD5 encrypting passwords is a **super bad idea** and I hope you have a way of using something else. Please follow the [best practices for handling passwords](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) to avoid endangering your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments above imply, you aren't escaping special characters in the text of your file. So any apostrophes for example would upset the SQL syntax. For example, what happens if someone is named O'Reilly?

```
INSERT INTO members (name, ...) VALUES ('O'Reilly', ...)
```

The apostrophe inside the string looks like it ends the string, which confuses MySQL.

You also aren't checking for success or failure of your call to `mysql_query()`, so you don't know how many are causing errors.

*Always check the return value* of `mysql_query()`. It return **false** to indicate an error, and then you should output `mysql_error()`. This is the most common beginner-level mistake when programming MySQL.

```
if (mysql_query($query) === false) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

To fix this by escaping special characters, read the documentation and examples for [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

As others have stated, using prepared statements with query parameters also solves the issues with special characters, without requiring escaping. Prepared statements aren't supported in the old ext/mysql API, that's why it's deprecated.

But a further suggestion for you that will solve the errors and make your data import much faster is to use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html).  I tested the following:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'members.db' INTO TABLE members FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';;' 
  (surname, names, home, affil, country, email, private, interest, specialty, jointime, password) 
  SET salt = UNHEX(MD5(RAND())), password = MD5(CONCAT(password, salt));
```

I also agree with others that MD5 is not considered best practice for hashing passwords. Use [SHA2()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) instead.